# Angular 8 Testing - Devextreme Grid getDataSource() not Working with State Storing

Tags: angular, devexpress, karma-jasmine, devextreme, angular-test

I am writing an Angular 8 test that checks if a `dx-data-grid` correctly lists and renders the data. Here is what my setup roughly looks like:

**HTML**

```
<dx-data-grid id="grid" [dataSource]="data">
  <dxo-state-storing [enabled]="true" type="localStorage" storageKey="storage-key"></dxo-state-storing>
  <dxi-column dataField="field1"></dxi-column>
  <dxi-column dataField="field2"></dxi-column>
</dx-data-grid>
```

**Typescript**

```
export class MyComponent {
    @Input() data;
}
```

**Test**

```
describe('MyComponent', () => {
    let component: MyComponent;
    let fixture: ComponentFixture<MyComponent>;

    beforeEach(async(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({ /* ... */ }).compileComponents();
    }));

    beforeEach(() => {
        fixture = TestBed.createComponent(MyComponent);
        component = fixture.componentInstance;
        fixture.detectChanges();
    });

    it('should list all items', () => {
        component.data= mockData;
        fixture.detectChanges();

        const gridElement = fixture.debugElement.query(
            By.css('#grid')
        );
        const dxGrid = <DxDataGridComponent>gridElement.componentInstance;
        dxGrid.instance.option('loadingTimeout', undefined);

        // Here is where the error occurs
        // dxGrid.instance.getDataSource() is undefined
        dxGrid.instance.getDataSource().load();

        const dataSource = dxGrid.dataSource;
        expect(dataSource.length).toBe(mockData.length);
        mockData.forEach(i => expect(dataSource).toContain(i));
    });

});
```

---

The test shown above fails with the following error

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'load' of undefined
```

However, wehen removing the following html from the template:

```
<dxo-state-storing [enabled]="true" type="localStorage" storageKey="storage-key"></dxo-state-storing>
```

...the test passes!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dx-data-grid widget loads state from localStorage in setTimeout. Try to use fakeAsync() and tick() to simulate time in the test.

Answer (score 2):

I basically found a workaround but I am not really satisfied with it:

```
it('should list all items', async () => {
    component.data= mockData;
    fixture.detectChanges();

    // workaround
    await new Promise( resolve => setTimeout( () => resolve(), 0 ) );
    // ---

    const gridElement = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('#grid'));
    const dxGrid = <DxDataGridComponent>gridElement.componentInstance;
    dxGrid.instance.option('loadingTimeout', undefined);
    dxGrid.instance.getDataSource().load();

    const dataSource = dxGrid.dataSource;
    expect(dataSource.length).toBe(mockData.length);
    mockData.forEach(i => expect(dataSource).toContain(i));
});
```

So it seems, that the grid isn't completely initialized when I want to load it's data.

Comment: This solution does not seem to work anymore with Angular 9.1.x.